# Azure Data Factory convert EnqueuedTimeUtc to Unix timestamp

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, unix-timestamp, azure-eventhub

I have a Data Flow that gets data from an EventHub.

[image]

The events have a system property called **EnqueuedTimeUtc:**

[image]

I want to convert the value of **EnqueuedTimeUtc** to Unix timestamp or at least to DateTime
in Data Factory.

There's aso a property called **SystemProperties**. It has a property called x-opt-enqueued-time. I want to get the value of **x-opt-enqueued-time** as a column.

[image]

But if I try to Parse the **SystemProperties** column I got the following error:

[image]

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toTimestamp('04/12/2022 08:40:39 PM','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') - toTimestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')

Comment: I tried with this solution and I noticed that it's not working if the time is PM. It takes the date as AM.

Comment: I change the format to 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a' and now it works! toTimestamp('04/12/2022 08:40:39 PM','MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a') - toTimestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')

Comment: Ah, I missed that extra part of the format, good catch